# what is the "+" meaning in css selector

Tags: css, scrapy

thanks in advance,recently I'm learning scrapy and I don't what is the "+" meaning ,here is my code[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MaiS8.png)

Comment: did you try to find it on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator)?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_pluss.asp

Answer (score -1):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator

it means Adjacent sibling combinator.

```css
div + p {
  color: red
  }
```

```html
<body>
  <div>div</div>
  <p>p1</p>
  <p>p2</p>
</body>
```

you can run the code snippet, then you will find only the first paragraph is red, just because it is adjacent sibling of div element. Meanwhile the second paragraph is not red.